# Deploying to Multiple Environments with Team Foundation Build 2015

Tags: deployment, tfs, build, azure-devops, visual-studio-2015

I'm new to TFS / Visual Studio Online. I'd like to use Team Foundation Build 2015 to automate my builds / deployments but I'm having trouble finding any documentation (presumably because it's all a bit new!).

However - it looks promising, so I'm hoping someone here who's a bit more familiar with it may be able to help.

I have successfully setup a build definition which will retrieve my source, build the Visual Studio project and create and store the build artefacts.

What I'd then like to do is automatically trigger the deployment of these artefacts to a development server. I assume this would be done by another agent installed on that server, running a different build definition.

If all goes well, I'd then like to be able to trigger the deployment of the same artefacts out to other environments (staging, and ultimately live).

Assuming this really is what I should be doing (I'm open to suggestions), I'm stumbling on the following pieces of the puzzle...

1. How do I create a build definition which retrieves the artefacts created by another definition?
2. How do I wire everything up such that the development server deployment is triggered automatically on the success of the 'build' build definition?
3. How do I arrange for the manual triggering of the deployment of successful builds through to staging / live?

Comment: What's a development server? You mean a server in test environent, right?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you are a little ahead of the curve here. The new deployment engine sound at build that is coming for 2015 is not ready yet. As such it is not in TFS 2015 and is not even yet available in VSO. It is coming however.

You can mitigate this by using release management to do your release. While some of the work is throw away code, most of the journey to getting it working isn't as the PowerShell you write can be reused once the new 2015 engine becomes available.

Comment: Anything new on this front here in 2017